# Ao inserir dados no EditText, um TextView e um outro EditText começam a se mover?

Tags: android, edittext, textview

No início está tudo normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece realmente algo estranho quando insiro algum conteúdo no EditText:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um TextView e um EditText começam a se mover para a direita, na medida que vou inserindo caracteres, sejam eles quais forem, infnitamente, até saírem para fora da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a explicação para isso? Como resolver?

**Activity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.ruleoftree;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main02Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etProduto01;
    private TextView tvFinalResult;
    private String produto;
    private EditText etPreco01, etPreco02, etQuantidade01, etQuantidade02, etUnidade01, etUnidade02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main02);

        etProduto01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etProduto01);
        etProduto01.setHint("opcional");

        etQuantidade01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etQuantidade01);
        etQuantidade02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etQuantidade02);
        etQuantidade01.setHint("g ou ml");
        etQuantidade02.setHint("g ou ml");

        addPreco();

        etUnidade01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUnidade01);
        etUnidade02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUnidade02);

        tvFinalResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFinalResult);
        tvFinalResult.setText(String.valueOf(""));

        addProduto();

    }

    private void addPreco(){

    }

    private void addProduto(){

        etProduto01.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                produto=s.toString();
                tvFinalResult.setText(String.valueOf(produto));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Note que o código acima está em desenvolvimento, parei de desenvolvê-lo por causa desse BUG bizarro.

**layout.xml:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.ruleoftree.Main02Activity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Produto:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelProduto"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelProduto"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/etProduto01" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPreco01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Preço 2:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelPreco02"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelPreco02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/etPreco02" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvFinalResult" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Quantidade 1:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPreco01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Quantidade 2:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade02"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/etQuantidade01" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etQuantidade02"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Unidades 1:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etQuantidade01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Unidades 2:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelUnidade02"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
        android:id="@+id/etUnidade01" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelUnidade02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/etUnidade02" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Preço 1:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etProduto01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Coloque o xml dessa view.

Comment: Coloque o xml do layout activity_main02 inteiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na propriedade **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"**, utilizada pelo TexView: Quantidade1 e EditText de Unidade 1, como você referência o posicionamento com base no EditText, quando você modifica um valor do campo, a referência da posisão também muda. Substitua **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"** por **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"**. O XML está abaixo:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main02"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="genesysgeneration.ruleoftree.Main02Activity">
<TextView
    android:text="Produto:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelProduto"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelProduto"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/etProduto01" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPreco01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Preço 2:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelPreco02"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelPreco02"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/etPreco02" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvFinalResult" />

<TextView
    android:text="Quantidade 1:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPreco01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Quantidade 2:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade02"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/etQuantidade01" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etQuantidade02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelQuantidade02"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Unidades 1:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etQuantidade01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<TextView
    android:text="Unidades 2:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelUnidade02"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelUnidade01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult"
    android:id="@+id/etUnidade01" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabelUnidade02"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/etUnidade02" />

<TextView
    android:text="Preço 1:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvLabelPreco01"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etProduto01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Vlw mano!!! Quando modifico a linha em questão, a linha em seguida (android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult") apresenta erro aí foi só apagar e deu tudo certo.

Comment: Sem problema, a comunidade é para nos ajudar. Sobre o erro que esta linha: (android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvFinalResult") apresentou contigo,  pode dizer qual foi o problema? No meu compilou e rodou direito.